# How to pass a variable in c program as an argument to the batch file?

Tags: c, batch-file, system, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

```
include<stdio.h>
include<stdlib.h>
  int main()
    {
      char a[20]="hello world";
system("./cool.bat a");\\here I need to pass the array as argument to batch file
       }
```

I believe you got what I wanted to say. I want to pass an array of the c program, as an argument to batch file. But if i say

```
   system("./omnam.bat a") \\ its taking a as an argument
```

How do i make it? How can i send a variable or array of c program as an argument to the batch file. Suppose i might have an integer I in a c program holding a value 15.How can i pass it as an argument to the batch file ? Can anyone please post an example of it with some c file and batch file.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the string at runtime using [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[20]="hello world";
    char command[256];
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "./cool.bat %s", a);
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

However, keep in mind that the `system` function is very dangerous, especially when you pass non-constant strings.  For security purposes, **be absolutely sure that no arbitrary user-generated strings can be passed into it**.

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to build a char[] consisting of the batch command, and the variable contents to pass to it

Comment: did not get you can you explain it more clearly? can You write some code for me please?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can write the batch file using standard IO and then execute it? Should be the same right?